# Xamarin iOS - Image not found

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Visual Studio 2019 - Windows
Xamarin Forms v4.60800

I am getting the following error when compiling my iOS Project

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file

```
"/Users/.../Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/xxx.Mobile.iOS/b97b05343d52097d681db173220d856c/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/optimized/LogoWithTitleRight.png"
File name: '/Users/.../Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/xxx.Mobile.iOS/b97b05343d52097d681db173220d856c/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/optimized/LogoWithTitleRight.png'
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x00259] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:274 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:106 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare,int,System.IO.FileOptions)
  at System.IO.FileSystem.CopyFile (System.String sourceFullPath, System.String destFullPath, System.Boolean overwrite) [0x00025] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/FileSystem.Unix.cs:54 
  at System.IO.File.Copy (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName, System.Boolean overwrite) [0x00056] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs:74 
  at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.SmartCopyTaskBase.CopyFile (System.String source, System.String target, System.String targetItemSpec) [0x0002d] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.Core/Tasks/SmartCopyTaskBase.cs:67 
  at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.SmartCopyTaskBase.Execute () [0x000a4] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.Core/Tasks/SmartCopyTaskBase.cs:100 xxx.Mobile.iOS
```

However, the LogoWithTitleRight.png image **is** in the Resources folder.

Originally my image was added as a link, but now it is physically there.

This is happening for a few images but not all (if I remove all references to that image, then it fails on the next image etc)

I have cleaned the solution, closed Visual Studio, deleted obj/bin folders from iOS and PCL projects.  But I still get the same error.

any ideas?

Comment: Have you added them to your csproj file?

Comment: yes...   
  <ItemGroup>
    <BundleResource Include="..\xxx.Mobile\Images\LogoWithTitleRight.png">
      <Link>Resources\LogoWithTitleRight.png</Link>
    </BundleResource>
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: Is there a certain 'type' of PNG that iOS does not like?  I just created a new project added the same two images to my splash screen, got same error.  Replaced the failing on with another PNG and it worked.  However, comparing the PNG properties reports they are the same

Comment: Can you try clearing the build cache on the mac? OPen a terminal on your mac and enter the following command: `rm -rf /Users/.../Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/xxx.Mobile.iOS/` replacing the "xxx" with the first part of your app name (I assume you changed it to "xxx" here to obscure your app's name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I fixed it (for others).

I opened the offending image in GIMP (Photoshop for poor people).
Selected the whole image.
Copied it.
Then pasted as new image.
Then saved that PNG.

Compiled my solution.  It now gave the same error on another image.  Did the process again for that image and 3 others and now it is all working.

Android was always fine with the images.